# Deriving two columns from another table when one of them is being ordered in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am running this query in MySQL

```
SELECT id_files, FileAlias, FileEXT, FileSize, FileExtension, UploadDate, category, COUNT(id_downloadInfo) AS "counter", DownloadDate as "lastlydownloaded"
FROM files 
LEFT JOIN categories ON files.category_id = categories.id_categories 
JOIN users ON files.users_id_users = users.id_users 
JOIN downloadinfo ON files.id_files = downloadinfo.files_id_files
WHERE organisations_id_organisations = 1 AND UserOnly = 0 AND files_id_files = 21
ORDER BY DownloadDate DESC LIMIT 1;
```

It does the job except the lastly download column is not being sorted.
I tried to do this with subquery but you cannot sort within it.

I am trying to connect query with two other tables when one of them have ordered result.

Is it possible to have it within one table?

Return output is
[image: sql output]

Which is correct except lastly downloaded date which should be:

[image: actual output]

Here's how the files table looks like
[image: FILES QUERY]

Here's download info query with all the data (users_id_users indicates on specific user).
[image: download info query]

Comment: Are you expecting it to find the latest date *before* applying the `WHERE` conditions?

Comment: Please post sample data and the expected result. Post it as text so we can copy and paste it into test code.

Comment: @Barmar afterwards because only then the specific file (files_id_files) is indicated.

Comment: In that case this should do what you want. It joins all the tables, applies the `WHERE` conditions, and then returns the row of the results with the latest date.

Comment: @Barmar I've uploaded some sample data. The problem is that it does not return latest date. Even if I change ordering to ascending, the date remains the same.

Comment: That sample data is useless. I told you to post it as text

Comment: Keep in mind that when you have a COUNT aggregate function in the SELECT list and no GROUP BY clause, the implication is `GROUP BY ( )`, which means one group and one result row for that group with one aggregate for the entire set of base rows.  The `LIMIT 1` is useless.  The `ORDER BY` is useless, and all the other expressions in the SELECT list are basically invalid (although MySQL can be configured to ignore the problem).  Be sure you understand that before continuing on your path to a solution.

Comment: Use a separate query to get the count. You can then join with that to add it to the result.

Comment: So I edited SELECT section and put counter in brackets (SELECT COUNT(id_downloadInfo) FROM downloadinfo WHERE files_id_files = 21) and it works perfectly. Thank you @JonArmstrong for reminding of that issue ;) As well as Bramar for trying to help out.